# set plot background colour when `axes` is not referenced

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

I have the a function to create stacked bar plots to process `df`s similar to this sample one:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

numrows = 5
index = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']
test = pd.DataFrame({
    'Yes': (0.4083, 0.4617, 0.284, 0.607, 0.3634, 0.4075),
    'No':  (0.5875, 0.5383, 0.716, 0.393, 0.635, 0.5925),
    'Other': (0.00417, 0, 0, 0, 0.0016668,0)},
    index = index)
```

The rump function looks like this

```
def bar_plot(df):
    N = len(df) # number of rows
    ind = np.arange(N)
    width = 0.35
    num_y_cats = len(df.columns)

    p_s = []
    p_s.append(plt.bar(ind, df.iloc[:, 0], width, color='#000000'))
    for i in range(1, len(df.columns)):
        p_s.append(plt.bar(ind, df.iloc[:, i], width, color = ''.join(('#', 6 * str(i))), bottom = np.sum(df.iloc[:,:i], axis=1)))
    plt.ylabel('[%]')
    plt.title('Title')            
    x_ticks_names = tuple([item for item in df.index])
    plt.xticks(ind, x_ticks_names)
    plt.yticks(np.arange(0, 1.1, 0.1))

    plt.legend(p_s, df.columns, bbox_to_anchor = (0.5, -0.35), loc = 'lower center', ncol = 3, borderaxespad = 0)
    plt.show()
    plt.close()
```

I want to change the design of the background and the legend background - but both the documentation and similar questions on this matter only result in responses suggesting to use the methods of the `axes` object(s) - which I, however, have not explicitly used anywhere.
Thus, I am confused where I have modify the background layout (e.g. setting it to white or yellow).

Many thanks in advance for any pointers and help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an axis instance using `subplots()` and then use that to plot the bar chart. Then you can set the face color for the axes and the legend box as shown below

```
def bar_plot(df):
    N = len(df) # number of rows
    ind = np.arange(N)
    width = 0.35
    num_y_cats = len(df.columns)
    fig, ax = plt.subplots() # <--- Create an axis instance
    p_s = []
    p_s.append(ax.bar(ind, df.iloc[:, 0], width, color='#000000'))
    for i in range(1, len(df.columns)):
        p_s.append(plt.bar(ind, df.iloc[:, i], width, color = ''.join(('#', 6 * str(i))), bottom = np.sum(df.iloc[:,:i], axis=1)))
    plt.ylabel('[%]')
    plt.title('Title')            
    x_ticks_names = tuple([item for item in df.index])
    plt.xticks(ind, x_ticks_names)
    plt.yticks(np.arange(0, 1.1, 0.1))
    ax.set_facecolor('yellow') # <--- Set the figure background color
    leg = plt.legend(p_s, df.columns, bbox_to_anchor = (0.5, -0.35), loc = 'lower center', ncol = 3, borderaxespad = 0)
    leg_frame = leg.get_frame()
    leg_frame.set_facecolor('lightgreen') # <--- Set the legend background color
    plt.show()
    plt.close()
```

[image]

Comment: Uih, what is `ax.axes`? I've not seen this one ever before. (though it [exists](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/7e8536f086a8730bda3b63646c1cf9e7bef180b9/lib/matplotlib/axes/_base.py#L459)) Why not `ax.set_facecolor(..)` directly?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingEarnest : Haha. Yes, I was just experimenting with tab completions and found that this works too. I will edit my answer :)